# Getting option value from Javascript and do a validation

Tags: javascript

I wanted to include in European countries to my dropdown `<select>` tag.  I want to make calculation depending on the country. What I meant is: if user chooses "Austria" from the dropdown list, calculation will be made for Austria. To do that, I have to get that Austria value from the `<option>` tag and make some validation. I tried to get the `<option>` value (country name) using by `.innerHTML` but it did not work. Could you help me with this? Thanks. :)

I will share my code below.

```
   //HTML
   <select>
    <option>Austria</option>
    <option>Belgium</option>
    <option>Bulgaria</option>
    <option>Czechia</option>
    <option>Denmark</option>
    <option>Finland</option>
    <option>France</option>
    <option>Germany</option>
    <option>Greece</option>
    <option>Hungary</option>
    <option>Iceland</option>
    <option>Ireland</option>
    <option>Italy</option>
    <option>Latvia</option>
    <option>Luxembourg</option>
    <option>Netherlands</option>
    <option>Norway</option>
    <option>Poland</option>
    <option>Portugal</option>
    <option>Slovak Republic</option>
    <option>Slovenia</option>
    <option>Spain</option>
    <option>Sweden</option>
    <option>Switzerland</option>
    <option>Turkey</option>
    <option>United Kingdom</option>


</select>

//JAVASCRIPT

var myButton = document.getElementById("calculate-button");
var myAmount = document.getElementById("input-amount");
var myText = document.getElementById("h3-amount");
var currencyUSD = "$"
var currencyEUR = "€"
var options = document.querySelectorAll("option");

myButton.addEventListener("click",function(){


for(var i = 0;i<options.length;i++){
if(options[i].innerHTML === "Austria"){

  calc(0.20);
 }
}


 })

 function taxCalc(tax){
 return myAmount.value * tax;
}


  function calc(taxRate){
    if(myAmount.value.length > 0) {
    myText.innerHTML = "Your Tax: " + parseFloat(taxCalc(taxRate)) + " " + currencyEUR;
    myAmount.value="";

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add value property to `option` then on change get the value property and call your function to do calculation

```js
document.getElementById("calculate-button").addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  console.log(this.value)

})
```

```html
<select id='calculate-button'>
  <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
  <option value='Belgium'>Belgium</option>
  <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I will try this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I  set the value for every single `<option>` for all countries. I can easily do `console.log` to `this.value`. Everything works well at that point.

But the problem is, I have to use my `calc()` function when user clicks the button and I must do the validation. Here is some part of my code. I couldn't do the logic. :(

```
var options = document.getElementById("select-list");


options.addEventListener('change', function() {
console.log(this.value) //works well here

 //for example I wanted to do this. 

 if(this.value === "austria"){
  calc(2);
 }

  else if(this.value ==="belgium"){
  calc(3);
 }

 })
```